# Angular js - The URL for PUT request to service not been added

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, rest

Here is my script:

```
var shipResource = $resource('http://localhost\\:8083/consignments/:cId', null, {ship: {method: 'PUT'}});

$scope.shipConsignment = function() {
   if($scope.selectedConsignment != null){
        var consignId = $scope.selectedConsignment.consignmentId;
        console.log(consignId) //works fine
       shipResource.ship({cId: "consignId"}); //not working? cId is not added to URL
    }
};
```

And HTML:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="shipConsignment()">Ship</button>
```

One the service side I have a function for PUT request for URL: localhost:8083/consignment/{consignmentId}.

but the request is being sent to localhost:8083/consignment. This give me 405 method not allow. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I change the method:'GET' it adds the consinId to the url but not for PUT.

Comment: i found its a CORS problem

Answer (score 0):

Then Try this :

```
$resource('http://localhost\\:8083/consignments/:id', {Id: "@cId"}, {ship: {method: 'PUT'}});
```